# HP Proliant DL 380 G7 Over Temp issue - doesn't boot

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

We have had a HP Proliant DL 380 G7 delivered yesterday and since then I am working to get it to boot - without success.

If I put in the PSU's (3x460), I wait for a bit and then try to switch it on but the LED's show the following immediately and the system seems to try to reboot:

- Power button yellow
- Over temp yellow
- Health red and blinking

The fans are all working, so do the PSU's. The system has two Xeon CPU's, 16GB of ram (8 per CPU) and two 146GB SAS. I swaped the PSU's, the DIMM's (according to the manuals), left the SAS's out, then in, I have used all maintance switch combinations I could think of and looked everywhere in the net but noone seems to have had this issue. But I can't get out of that boot-loop.

I figured it has to be a broken temp sensor but since I can't even access iLo, I don't know which one. I'm going mad over this.

I'm grateful for any advice and will provide any additional information if necessary.

Comment: `We have had a HP Proliant DL 380 G7 delivered yesterday and since then I am working to get it to boot - without success.` - Shouldn't you be talking to the party that you purchased it from?

Comment: You're right and we already reached out but I fear we shouldn't expect competent help from them. That's why I consult SF now.

Comment: I have the same problem DL380 G7, in storage for a year, now on bootup "over temp" light comes on and it refused to boot. It is ice cold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we figured that one or more temperature sensors must be faulty so the boot initiation is interrupted right at the start. Since nothing does load (not even iLo), we can't tell what sensor is faulty. Since all sensors are soldered onto the board(s), you can't swap them easily and there's so many of them! My advice: get another whole unit!